# Hibernate Query : How to search in multiple columns?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a table XYZ. It has multiple columns containing tag1, tag2 and tag3. Only 3 tags columns.

Entries in database is like :

```
Header: id, tag1, tag2, tag3
id1, ABC
id2, ABC, XYZ
id3
id4 PQR, XYZ
id5 ABC, XYZ, PQR
```

If user passes [ABC] then id1, id2 and id3 should be returned.
If user passes [ABC, PQR, XYZ] then it should return id5.

What would be the Hibernate Query for it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the OR predicate.

```
entityManager.createQuery("FROM Entity e WHERE e.tag1 IN :list OR e.tag2 IN :list OR e.tag3 IN :list")
    .setParameter("list", userInputList)
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: No. This won't work for all the cases. I solved it by iterating list and using "'value' in (e.tag1, e.tag2, e.tag3). Still thanks for the reply.

Here is my code :  if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(getTagList())) {
            query += " ( ";
            for (int index = 0; index < getTagList().size(); index++) {
                query += "  ('" + getTagList().get(index) + "') IN (qd.tag1, qd.tag2, qd.tag3) AND ";
            }
            query = query.substring(0, query.length() - 4);
            query += " ) AND ";
        }

Comment: Not sure why you think that this doesn't work, but if you have a solution that works for you that's ok.

Comment: Lets say record #1 has one tag TAG1. And record #2 has two tags TAG1 and TAG2. And list is [TAG1, TAG2]. If I write query e.tag1 IN :list OR e.tag2 IN :list it will return first result as well (since one of item found in record #1). But as I mentioned in the question I needed record #2 only in this case. But thank you for the reply. :-)